# What is the maximum inverse pairs will I have when I build a heap?

Tags: heaps

Suppose that I have 7 different integers stored in an array. Among those arrange-
ments that can be viewed as a min heap, what is the maximum number of inverse pairs within the array?

Comment: By brute-force: generate all permutations of the integers from 1 to 7, discard those that violate the heap condition and count the inversions.

Comment: (I think it's possible to construct such - too lazy to try and prove.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have $7$ (or rather $2^{n}-1$) arbitrary numbers, then brute force is the way to go. However, there are some observations if you construct a heap with all distinct numbers in the range $1 ... 2^{n}-1$.

Intuitively(for the lack of a rigorous mathematical proof), a min heap formed by inserting in *reverse postorder* or *converse preorder* traversal of the numbers  $1 ... 2^{n}-1$ sorted in ascending order should give the maximum number of inversions. Example

[image: min heap constructed using converse preorder from a sorted sequence]

It is easy to see that at every level, the **rightmost** element, will not have inversions. For the remaining elements, visually, the inversions would look something like this

[image: min heap inversions]

i.e. every element is paired up with all elements of remaining subtrees of height $h-i$ for a heap having height $h$ and a level $i$. From here an expression for the no. of inversions can be derived. We simply sum up the inversions at each level, for all levels.
$$no\;of\;elements\;at\;level\;i = no\;of\;subtrees\;of\;height\;h-i = 2^{i}$$
$$no\;of\;elements\;in\;a\;complete\;binary\;tree\;of\;height\;h = 2^{h+1}-1$$
$$no\;of\;inversions\;at\;level\;i = (2^{h-i+1}-1)*\sum_{k=1}^{2^{i}-1}k$$
$$total\;no\;of\;inversions = \sum_{i=1}^{h}(2^{h-i+1}-1)*\sum_{k=1}^{2^{i}-1}k$$

Further simplification of the expression can be done, i'd say this form preserves the "meaning" of the expression in a way.

Substituting $h=2$, we get $9$ as the no. of inversions for heap having elements $1...7$, which can be verified by counting the number of inversions(coloured links except black) in the picture above.

Answer (score 1):

By exhaustive search, $[1, 5, 2, 7, 6, 4, 3]$ has $9$ inversions.